# Chrome for Android, overriding the bluish color for active links

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been at this for over an hour.  Chrome on Android seems to put a bluish color over active links or the parent of the active links.  See the screenshot for what I am talking about.  That is a nav with a ul, and an li and a tag for the "HOME" link there.  I'm trying to make it look like the one below it all of the time.  I've tried everything, a:active, li:active overriding the background color, but it always has that blue.

Anybody know which style it is in the user agent stylesheet that does that so I can override it?  Or is it not possible to override?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile themes?

Comment: Yes, but I only have that js library included on one page.  I can see this "blue" across all sorts of different websites when I click on a link, so don't think it has something to do with jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK figured it out.  It was -webkit-tap-highlight-color, very much hidden in the dev tools.